# How to return JSObject from JSFunction?

Tags: haskell, threepenny-gui

I'd like to return a reference to a Javascript object from an FFI function definition in order to be able to manipulate the object later on:

```
import           Data.Aeson
import           Foreign.JavaScript (JSObject, NewJSObject, unsafeCreateJSObject)
import           Foreign.RemotePtr (RemotePtr)
import           Graphics.UI.Threepenny.Core hiding (text)

mkJSObject :: JSFunction NewJSObject -> UI JSObject
mkJSObject f = askWindow >>= liftIO . flip unsafeCreateJSObject f

polyLine :: [[Double]] -> Value -> UI JSObject
polyLine points = mkJSObject . f points
  where
    f :: [[Double]] -> Value -> JSFunction NewJSObject
    f = ffi "L.polyline(%1, %2).addTo(map)"
```

But the underlying Javascript Window doesn't seem to be publicly accessible. Is there another way for creating references to Javascript objects?

Comment: That looks fine to me. It appears to me that you have answered your own question?

Comment: Yes, but maybe the answer is helpful for others, too. Thanks for threepenny-gui btw, well designed and extremely useful!

Comment: Of course. :-) But could you cut the answer and paste it below? That would make it easier for others to understand later. And thank you, I'm glad you like it. :-)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an option for answering my own question, I can just add comments. Could you maybe add the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, forget it, I hadn't seen the big blue button at the bottom ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually much simpler: Just return a JSObject from JSFunction and it will be marshalled correctly:

```
polyLine :: [[Double]] -> Value -> UI JSObject
polyLine points = callFunction . f points
  where
    f :: [[Double]] -> Value -> JSFunction JSObject
    f = ffi "L.polyline(%1, %2).addTo(map)"
```